# Firebase Auth: Not able to authenticate a mobile number that is no longer whitelisted for test

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Using a mobile number that was whitelisted for testing in a real world authentication throws an exception, none whitelisted numbers do nott

Have tested with a non whitelisted number and this does not throw an exception.

In order to test the phone auth functionality of my app, I added my mobile number to the whitelist. After completing the coding and testing. I removed my number from the whitelist and wanted to do a real world authentication.

The auth methods throws an exception

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred.
>   [ DEVELOPMENT MODE MISMATCH:Development mode Verification Proof in
>   non-development mode request. ]

Has anyone else had any experience of this and are there any known solutions to this?

EDIT: Have removed the number entirely from the auth user list, have even tried creating an auth user with the number, none of these make a difference.

Also this is totally my own fault for rushing in and not reading the firebase documentation properly. It does stipulate that whitelisted "test" numbers should be fictious and not real / user account related.

Comment: Is this a consequence of using a real world number as a test whitelist number? And does this then mean that Number is forever more regarded as a fictional number by Firebase?

Comment: Try deleting the existing account with that phone number and try again.

Comment: @bojeil Thanks for that I have tried that. Still no joy

Comment: I have done exactly the same: added my real phone number to the whitelist by mistake. Removing it seems to make no difference - seems it's forever whitelisted as fictitious :-(

Comment: I ended up firing an email off to them asking about it and what could be done. Whilst there advice was, follow the guide, it seems that once the number has been removed and has been off the list for a while and the project is live, it does behave.